# NHibernate - flexible config files

Tags: nhibernate, configuration, dynamic, file

I am using NHibernate in a DAL layer dll.  Local config file(app.config) is being used for db connection.  This DAL component can be used in 2 different  exe's and a NUnit test harness.  Business requirement from Client is to have config information reside in exe's app.config file.
Is there a way to configure NHibernate to look for an app.config file based on the exe that it is compiled with? 
Then in the NUnit test harness, look for a default config file?

Thanks,
Marc

Comment: @Marc: Just to clarify; do you mean that all of your nhibernate settings are in the app.config file? or are you using an external hibernate.cfg.xml file for that?

Comment: How is that a "business" requirement?

Answer (score 1):

As Dan hinted, NHibernate's main config section can either be in a standalone hibernate.cfg.xml, OR it can be put in the application's config file. If you want NHibernate's core config to vary by the currently executing environment (different apps, or during testing), you can go the app.config route. If no hibernate.cfg.xml file is found, NHibernate is going to look in the currently executing app's app.config file.

Here is an example of putting the NHibernate config in an app.config file: http://www.martinwilley.com/net/code/nhibernate/appconfig.html